# What are the parameter estimation methods for the two methods in this paper?

Tags: r, statistics

[Automated Time Series Forecasting for Biosurveillance](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=923635)

in the above paper, page 4, two models, non-adaptive regression model, adaptive regression model, the non-adaptive regression model's parameter estimation method is "least squares", what is the parameter estimation for the adaptive regression model? is there any package in R to do parameter estimation for this kind of adaptive regression model? If I add more predictors in the adaptive regression model, can R still solve it? and how?